# Excel How to compare 2 Column Ranges

Tags: excel, excel-formula, comparison

I am trying to compare two set of column ranges in Excel.

i am aware of the standard comparison formula :

Eg. `=(A1=E1)`

What I am looking for is a replacement for the following formula
`=AND(A1=E1,B1=F1,C1=G1)`

since the number of columns is large I was thinking if it is possible to use a cell range.

Answer (score 1):

`=SUMPRODUCT(PRODUCT(--(A1:D1=E1:H1)))`

The `SUMPRODUCT` is to force it to evaluate as an Array Formula

The `PRODUCT` multiplies all of the values

The `--` converts `TRUE` into `1` and `FALSE` into `0`

`A1:D1=E1:H1`, evalauated as an Array Formula, gives the array `{A1=E1,B1=F1,C1=G1,D1=H1}`

So, the array is calcuated as a list of `TRUE` and `FALSE`.  The `--` converts this into a list of `1`s and `0`s, and the `PRODUCT` multiplies all the values in the list together.  (Multiplication of `1` and `0` is the same as `AND` with `TRUE` and `FALSE`) - if you use "Evaluate Formula", you can step through and watch it happen

**{EDIT}** *As Tom Sharpe pointed out in his answer, I've overcomplicated this slightly - you can use `AND` instead of `PRODUCT`, like so:*
`=SUMPRODUCT(--AND(A1:D1=E1:H1))`

Answer (score 1):

A bit slower than @Chronocidal, just to observe that

```
=AND(A1:C1=E1:G1)
```

also works if entered as an array formula using

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps,

```
=a1&b1&c1=e1&f1&g1
```

Larger ranges could be handled with the newer [textjoin](/questions/tagged/textjoin).

```
=textjoin("", true, a1:c1)=textjoin("", true, e1:g1)
```

If you don't have the newer TextJoin function, here is a quick VBA UDF (user defined function) that you can use to substitute.

```
function tj(rng as range, optional delim as string = ";") as string
   dim val as range, str as string
   for each val in rng
       str = str & delim & val.value2
   next val
   tj = mid(str, len(delim)+1)
end function
```

Comment: I have Office 2010 so text join does not seem to work.

Comment: added a udf for you

Comment: Suggest non-empty delimiter for the two formulas otherwise 1 23 4 would match 12 3 4 etc.